# RF24Network not compiling

Tags: rf24

I am trying to run a simple test of RF24Network which requires to use nrf_to_nrf library.
My compiler is pulling all the libraries and when is trying to compile I can see the object NRF_RADIO not being found/declared.

I tried to look around the doc in case I needed to include something extra but nothing... anybody has a simlar issue?

To clarify, I just tried any of the examples from the official library
https://github.com/nRF24/RF24Network/tree/master/examples

Oddly using Arduino IDE, the compiler is not throwing any errors but platformio is not able to compile.

Yes I checked that all the libraries were present when building. It seems like there is an extra library that Arduino automatically download? I can't find any reference of NRF_RADIO in any of RF24, RF24network and nrf_to_nrf.

```
                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ .pio/libdeps/huzzah/nrf_to_nrf/src/nrf_to_nrf.cpp:1172:155: error: 'RADIO_PCNF1_BALEN_Pos' was not declared in this scope
     NRF_RADIO->PCNF1 = (RADIO_PCNF1_WHITEEN_Disabled << RADIO_PCNF1_WHITEEN_Pos) | (RADIO_PCNF1_ENDIAN_Big << RADIO_PCNF1_ENDIAN_Pos) | ((a_width - 1) << RADIO_PCNF1_BALEN_Pos) | (pSize << RADIO_PCNF1_STATLEN_Pos) | (staticPayloadSize << RADIO_PCNF1_MAXLEN_Pos);
                                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ .pio/libdeps/huzzah/nrf_to_nrf/src/nrf_to_nrf.cpp:1172:190: error: 'RADIO_PCNF1_STATLEN_Pos' was not declared in this scope
     NRF_RADIO->PCNF1 = (RADIO_PCNF1_WHITEEN_Disabled << RADIO_PCNF1_WHITEEN_Pos) | (RADIO_PCNF1_ENDIAN_Big << RADIO_PCNF1_ENDIAN_Pos) | ((a_width - 1) << RADIO_PCNF1_BALEN_Pos) | (pSize << RADIO_PCNF1_STATLEN_Pos) | (staticPayloadSize << RADIO_PCNF1_MAXLEN_Pos);
                                                                                                                                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ .pio/libdeps/huzzah/nrf_to_nrf/src/nrf_to_nrf.cpp:1172:239: error: 'RADIO_PCNF1_MAXLEN_Pos' was not declared in this scope
     NRF_RADIO->PCNF1 = (RADIO_PCNF1_WHITEEN_Disabled << RADIO_PCNF1_WHITEEN_Pos) | (RADIO_PCNF1_ENDIAN_Big << RADIO_PCNF1_ENDIAN_Pos) | ((a_width - 1) << RADIO_PCNF1_BALEN_Pos) | (pSize << RADIO_PCNF1_STATLEN_Pos) | (staticPayloadSize << RADIO_PCNF1_MAXLEN_Pos);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ .pio/libdeps/huzzah/nrf_to_nrf/src/nrf_to_nrf.cpp: In member function 'void nrf_to_nrf::printDetails()': .pio/libdeps/huzzah/nrf_to_nrf/src/nrf_to_nrf.cpp:1182:20: error: 'NRF_RADIO' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You need to show the concerned source at least, optimally a minimal, complete, and reproducible example. BTW, each of us has a similar issue now and then, but I'm sure you don't want to know that.